# Tengo un problema de lógica

Tags: c#

estoy estudiando programación mediante un libro y un ejercicio propuesto me pide que: hacer un programa que a un grupo de personas pida sus edades, saque la media de edades la edad más alta y la edad más baja.
Cómo aún no llego a vectores, pretendo hacerlo todo mediante bucle do_while e if anidados.
public static void Main() {

```
     Console.WriteLine("Cuantas personas son: ");
     int NuneroDePersonas = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
     
     int contador = 0;
     double aux = 0,AuxiliarMayor=0,AuxiliarMenor=0, promedio= 0
     ,IngresaEdad,sumatoria=0;
     do{
         
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la edad de la "+(contador+1)+" Persona");
        IngresaEdad = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        
        if( IngresaEdad > aux){
            AuxiliarMayor = IngresaEdad;
        }else if(IngresaEdad < aux){
            AuxiliarMenor = IngresaEdad;
        }else{
            
        }
        contador++; 
        aux = IngresaEdad;
        
        sumatoria += IngresaEdad;
        
     }while(contador != NuneroDePersonas);
     
     promedio = sumatoria/NuneroDePersonas;
     Console.WriteLine("El promedio de edad es: "+promedio);
     Console.WriteLine("La Edad más alta es de: "+AuxiliarMayor);
     Console.WriteLine("La Edad más baja es de: "+AuxiliarMenor);
    }
```

El problema se da cuando quiero sacar la edad menor.
De antemano muchas gracias por tomar su tiempo para responder.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando estás comparando en el `else if` de `AuxiliarMenor` la variable `AuxiliarMenor` ya vale 0 en su declaración y la comparación de la edad la realizas con el dato ingresado en la anterior solicitud.

Por ejemplo, en tu código, si tienes 3 personas con las edades 1, 2 y 3 introducidas en ese orden, en la consola verías que la edad del mayor es 3, y la del menor es 0;
Si introduces las siguientes 3 edades en el orden de 1, 4, 2, entonces en la consola verías que la edad mas alta es 4, y la mas baja es 2.

En el primer caso se debe a que la variable está definida en 0, por lo que cualquier edad mayor a 0 no seria almacenada en `AuxiliarMenor`.
En el segundo caso, se debe a que la entrada de edad, está siendo comparada con la entrada directamente anterior.

Lo cual, se arregla almacenando el valor directamente en la correspondiente variable `AuxiliarMenor` y `AuxiliarMayor`, comparando que, la edad ingresada sea mayor o menor en cada caso a la almacenada, ó, la edad almacenada sea 0 ya que es el valor inicial de la variable.

Código de ejemplo:

```
public static void Main()
{
 Console.WriteLine("Cuantas personas son: ");
 int NuneroDePersonas = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
 
 int contador = 0;
 double AuxiliarMayor=0,AuxiliarMenor=0, promedio= 0
 ,IngresaEdad,sumatoria=0;
 do{
    
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la edad de la  Persona");
    IngresaEdad = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    
    if( IngresaEdad > AuxiliarMayor || AuxiliarMayor == 0){
        AuxiliarMayor = IngresaEdad;
    }
    
    if(IngresaEdad < AuxiliarMenor || AuxiliarMenor == 0){
        AuxiliarMenor = IngresaEdad;
    }
     
    contador++; 
    
    sumatoria += IngresaEdad;
    
 }while(contador != NuneroDePersonas);
 
 promedio = sumatoria/NuneroDePersonas;
 Console.WriteLine("El promedio de edad es: "+promedio);
 Console.WriteLine("La Edad más alta es de: "+AuxiliarMayor);
 Console.WriteLine("La Edad más baja es de: "+AuxiliarMenor);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
if( IngresaEdad > AuxiliarMayor ){
   AuxiliarMayor = IngresaEdad;
}
if(IngresaEdad < AuxiliarMenor ){
   AuxiliarMenor = IngresaEdad;
}
```

A la variable `aux` no le veo razón exista; tu error es que guardas en `aux` la edad más reciente *sin importar si es mayo, menor o algo y desde luego no la evaluas*.

Tu comparación debe ser el dato que ingresaron respecto al que actualmente es el mayor y posteriormente compararlo con el menor.

Ambas comparaciones las debes realizar; por ello tu `else if` también estaba erroneo ya que si entraba en la primera no hacia nada para la segunda.

Cosa aparte que te pongan un dato negativo; como incializas en `0` tanto el mayor como el menor, el primer dato que ingresen se asignaria como el mayor y el menor (dependiendo la edad) la 2da vez es donde ya alguno pudiera cambiar.